# Azure DevOps pipeline build name based on branch of different repository

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-yaml-pipelines

We'd like to name our builds in such a way that it includes the date and the branch name, so that we can easily find the correct artifact when we want to deploy to one of our environments.

We have a setup where we have two repositories: YAML and Code. The pipelines live in the YAML repo and the code that we want to build and deploy lives in the Code repo. I've got the build pipeline set up in such a way that the build gets triggered when changes are made to the codebase in the Code repository. However, when the build gets triggered, the build name contains the branch name of the YAML repo. Since we use the main branch of this repo for CI builds, the name of the build will be something like **2021-01-01 103015 main**.

This makes it difficult to find the correct artifact when we want to deploy, since everything seems to point to a main branch. Instead, we'd like the build name to be along the lines of **2021-01-01 103015 Feature1** where Feature1 is the branch of the Code repo.

This is how we set our build name in YAML:

```
name: $(Date:yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss) $(SourceBranchName)
```

Is there a way to get the branch name of the Code repo in the build name?

Comment: try `$(Build.SourceBranch)`

Comment: I've tried $(Build.SourceBranch) as well, but that gives **2021-01-01 103015 refs_heads_main** as build name.

Comment: ok, then you need to update this in code (i.e. you need for example a bash task that sets the "buildnumber") See here for an example https://bzzzt.io/post/2020-10/2010-10-28-update-build-name-with-var/ See my answer for a hasty example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  name: 'updateBranchName'
  displayName: 'Update Build Name'
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      echo "*** Build.SourceBranch: $(Build.SourceBranch)"
      $sourceBranch = $("$(Build.SourceBranch)" -replace "refs/heads/", "")
      echo "*** Strip branch name from SourceBranch: $sourceBranch"
      echo "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$((get-date).tostring("yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss")) - $sourceBranch"
```

Comment: As far as I remember this `(Date:yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss) ` will not work here. It is available in the name context but not as it used here.

Comment: good point. didnt check that. changed my code to powershell-native

Comment: This did the trick, thanks! Weird that the $(SourceBranchName) or $(Build.SourceBranchName) variables in YAML don't work, but they do in PowerShell. Hopefully fixes this to make it work properly out of the box.

Comment: They are probably evaluated at different stages and thus not everything is available everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Silent, the below works for me to have the Azure pipeline run description displayed as "BranchName-BuildNUmber-**
- task: PowerShell@2
inputs:
targetType: 'inline'
script: |

```
      $branchname = $env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH -replace "/", "-"
      $branchname = $env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH -replace "refs/heads/", ""
      $buildnumber = $env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER
  
      Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$branchname-$buildnumber"
```